# GCM - Detect Device Prescence

Tags: java, android, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to notify the server when a device connects and disconnects from the GCM platform?

Connection can be implemented easily enough at the application level since I would be able to send a message to my server via CCS. Detecting when the device is offline does not appear to be so simple.

I was hoping that there was a control message I could tap into to detect this?

Answer (score 0):

thenIn these types of scenarios's, the pinging methodology is the best. For example if your client suddenly looses all his batterypower and the phone suddenly dies. The client will therefore not be able to send a request to your server that he is no longer online. Simultaneously, on the server-side, he is still flagged as "online".

The pinging mechanism reduces this problem by proposing a solution such that "If a ping is not received in a timely manner then flag the user as offline".

The [Openfire plugin](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) at the server side is one of the best one available till now that does this job for you. You can give it a shot.

Hope that Helps!!

Answer (score 0):

There is the roster flag which indicates this:

```
 connectionConfiguration.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(true);
```